# Compute an average for each participant in long-form data

Tags: python, statistics, regression, seaborn, data-science

so I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | memory confidence | Test (1= correct, 2=incorrect) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 1 |
| 1 | 78 | 0 |
| 1 | 98 | 0 |
| 1 | 24 | 1 |
| 2 | 45 | 0 |
| 2 | 87 | 1 |

People answer questions on a test, and then rate their confidence.

I want to create a scatterplot (and ultimately run a regression analysis) on the relationship between a person's average level of confidence over the test, and the percentage that they got correct. Each person should be one point on the scatterplot.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if a scatter plot is the best visualization for this kind of data...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer:

```
df3 = df.groupby(['PID'])['accuracy','memory_confidence'].mean()

i = sns.lmplot(x = 'memory_confidence', y = 'accuracy', data = df3)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).